# Entity Framework Core (EF 7) many-to-many results always null

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have followed the instructions for the workaround for many-to-many described in [Issue #1368](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1368) and the [Docs Here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#many-to-many)... but when I try to navigate, it always returns null.

My Models:

```
    public class Organization
{
    public Guid OrganizationID { get; set; }

    //...

    public ICollection<OrganizationSubscriptionPlan> OrganizationSubscriptionPlans { get; set; }

}

public class SubscriptionPlan
{
    public int SubscriptionPlanID { get; set; }

    //...

    public ICollection<OrganizationSubscriptionPlan> OrganizationSubscriptionPlans { get; set; }


public class OrganizationSubscriptionPlan
{
    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public Guid OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubscriptionPlan")]
    public int SubscriptionPlanID { get; set; }
    public SubscriptionPlan SubscriptionPlan { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<OrganizationSubscriptionPlan>().HasKey(x => new { x.OrganizationID, x.SubscriptionPlanID });
    builder.Entity<OrganizationSubscriptionPlan>().HasOne(x => x.Organization).WithMany(x => x.OrganizationSubscriptionPlans).HasForeignKey(x => x.OrganizationID);
    builder.Entity<OrganizationSubscriptionPlan>().HasOne(x => x.SubscriptionPlan).WithMany(x => x.OrganizationSubscriptionPlans).HasForeignKey(x => x.SubscriptionPlanID);
}
```

And my Query:

```
var organizations = _context.Organizations
    .Include(o => o.OrganizationSubscriptionPlans);

foreach (var organization in organizations)
{
    //....
    var subscriptions = organization.OrganizationSubscriptionPlans
            .Select(s => s.SubscriptionPlan);
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^ why is subscriptions always null?
}
```

The "organizations" query returns the results as expected, including the list of OrganizationSubscriptionPlans within each one, but when I try to navigate to them in the foreach loop the "subscriptions" query returns null every time.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it's a Lazy Loading issue.  You have to "Include" the joining entity and then "ThenInclude" the other entity.

```
var organizations = _context.Organizations
    .Include(o => o.OrganizationSubscriptionPlans)
    .ThenInclude(s => s.SubscriptionPlan);
```

Answer (score 0):

ForeignKey attr is to decorate reference properties to indicate them what primitive property hold the FK value.

```
public class OrganizationSubscriptionPlan
{    
    public Guid OrganizationID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationID")]
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public int SubscriptionPlanID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubscriptionPlanID")]
    public SubscriptionPlan SubscriptionPlan { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to have solved the problem. Still getting null result on the "subscriptions" query.